# Binding error after selecting optionstext

Tags: knockout.js

Here is a dropdown list and a further element to check the binding:

```
<select data-bind = 
    "options: chains,
    optionsText: function (item) { return item.BusinessModel['Name'] },
    optionsCaption: 'Select...', 
    value: selectedChain">
</select>
<div data-bind = "text: selectedChain().Id"></div>
```

The viewModel and initialization looks like this:

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.chains = null;
    this.selectedChain = ko.observable();
}

$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("Chains", "GetAll")",
    success: function (result) {
        var model = new ViewModel();
        model.chains = result;
        model.selectedChain(result[0]); // Why?
        ko.applyBindings(model);
    }
});
```

Once the `optionsCaption` ("*Select...*") is selected in the combobox the binding is not working longer (no reset of the old / set of new values in the reference element). This is the reason why I need to initialize the `selectedChain`.
It seeems to me that there is something wrong with setting `null` to the selectedValue?!

Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to call  model.selectedChain(result[0]) after the ko.applyBindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 2nd binding `text: selectedChain().Id` is problematic - if you select the "Select..." option, then `selectedChain`'s value is undefined, and you can't do `.Id` on undefined. You need to add a check for that, e.g.:

```
<!-- ko if: selectedChain -->
    <div data-bind="text: selectedChain().Id"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

or:

```
<div data-bind="text: selectedChain() && selectedChain().Id"></div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FLD2V/

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem. So that means I need always consider the undefinded case in the bindings!?

Comment: Yea you need to remember that the binding string will get evaluated as javascript in the end. Using a `with` binding can help reduce clutter: `<!-- ko with: selectedChain --> <div data-bind="text: Id"></div> <!-- /ko -->`, especially when you'll want to display *more* than one field of that object